# How to extract characters from a cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

kind regards

I am working on some data and I need to extract from column A:A exactly only the dates that start in 2017 and end in number, that is to say with a length of 8 characters [20171015], the problem is that I am performing this operation in column C:C but due to the extension of some characters in some rows it does not bring me the totality of numbers that I am requesting. Is there an additional method to make this possible or can I fix the formula that I am using in a wrong way?

I appreciate your collaboration.

PS: the formula I am using is
=MID(A9,FIND(" ",A9,B9+1),9)

[worksheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B0Jzz9guYFU_L_t2kuKQS6fpmlHTPxMq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: On your example worksheet, which date values are not being returned  the way you wish?  And how would you want them returned?  I have no idea what you mean by *due to the extension of some characters in some rows it does not bring me the totality of numbers that I am requesting*

Comment: Also, what version of Excel?  Windows or Mac or other?

Comment: Dear thank you very much for your answer, I apologize for not providing the precise information, indeed I only require that you return me the string of numbers that begins with 2017 and that are before the symbol $ [20171015]. I would like to know if the proposed formula can be simplified [= MID (A9, FIND ("", A9, B9 + 1), 9)], or on the contrary I am doing a wrong step to make the calculation possible. I am using version of Excel 2013 on Windows. Grateful for your collaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-MID(A2,FIND(2,A2),{7;8}))
```

[image]

Comment: Dear, thank you very much for your attention and collaboration, it is a very precise formula for what I am looking for and it responds to what I need, a big hug!